# Why can I bind to ListBox but not to DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I set up LINQ-to-SQL / NorthWind in WPF.

The ListBox shows data but the DataGrid doesn't (no errors, just doesn't display anything).

I referenced WPFToolkit.dll.

Why is the DataGrid not displaying the data that ListBox can?

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestLinq343.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ShowCustomer">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryID}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=": "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <dg:DataGrid x:Name="TheDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></dg:DataGrid>
        <ListBox x:Name="TheListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShowCustomer}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**code behind:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using TestLinq343.Model;
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestLinq343
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
            var sortedProducts =
                from p in db.Products
                orderby p.UnitsInStock descending
                select p;

            TheDataGrid.ItemsSource = sortedProducts;
            TheListBox.ItemsSource = sortedProducts;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a XAML issue, this fixes it:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <dg:DataGrid x:Name="TheDataGrid"/>
        <ListView x:Name="TheListView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShowCustomer}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you did not specifiy datagrid columns. try setting the datagrids AutoGenerateColumns property to true.

Comment: tried that, still blank, autogeneratecolumns is true be default, in the walkthrough I'm following http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx, it defines the ItemsSource in the XAML but that shouldn't matter, should it?